# Can't Set Featured Image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have installed the [MarketPress plugin from WPMU](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/e-commerce/). I have an ongoing issue with featured images. When I try to set the featured image (in any post) it continually hangs on saving.

My problem is that I can't set the product image. In Chrome, when I use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to bring up the console and then try to set the image, I get a 404 not found for this specific snippet in `admin-ajax.php`:

```
POST http://www.salonoasis.biz/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:4
send jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
f.(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:4
WPSetAsThumbnail set-post-thumbnail.js:1
onclick
```

The rest of the script runs fine. I have increased the memory limit to 128M and my server provider (I am a reseller) has white listed the domain in mod_security. I have cleared my browser cache. I still have the problem!